# How to delete sheets based on a name criteria using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to delete existing sheets whose names match a criteria, but I keep running into the error below and I can't find out why.

The code I'm running:

```
const SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const allSheets = SS.getSheets();
const category = 'Block-A';
const newSheetName = 'BOQ ' + category;

for (let a = 0; a < allSheets.length; a++) {
  let existingSheetName = allSheets[a].getName();
  if (existingSheetName == newSheetName) {
    SS.deleteSheet(allSheets[a]);
  }
}
```

The error: `Sheet xxxxxxxxxx not found`

Appreciate your help.

Antonio

Comment: It looks like it should work. Try single stepping through the program.  Look for sheets that have spaces in their names or need to be trimmed somehow.

Comment: It does delete the right one at first, but it fails when going forward. I'll check for details. Thanks, @Cooper!

Comment: You should break after doing the first delete because all sheets have to have unique names so there will always be only one for a given name.

Comment: Part of the problem may be that when you delete one of the sheets in ss.getSheets() that Allsheets[a] will not exist for the last one because one of them has been deleted because that one is still in your array.

Comment: So, generating the names and pushing them into a list. If any of those exist, then delete the sheet will work thoroughly, then... Thank you, @Cooper

Comment: What is `xxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: Hi, @TheMaster! This is equivalent to the sheet ID. Something like: 11234567894

Comment: Based on your code, you are only deleting the 'BOQ Block-A' Sheet. The first deletion in your code should be enough since Google Sheets can't have duplicate sheet name and the other sheets wont met the criteria in the if-statement.  Are you sure that is the line generates error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through the comments on the question, this is what has worked for me:

First, make sure that the sheet names are listed. In my case, I got a column `clientCategories` whose each value would become a sheet name:

```
let sheetsToDel = [];
for (let a = 0; a < clientCategories.length; a++) {
  sheetsToDel.push('BOQ ' + clientCategories[a])
}
```

Then, I'd go through all the sheets and delete them:

```
for (let a = 0; a < allSheets.length; a++) {
  const sheetName = allSheets[a].getName()
  for (let r = 0; r < sheetsToDel.length; r++) {
    if (sheetName == sheetsToDel[r]) {
      SS.deleteSheet(allSheets[a]);
    }
  }
}
```

There may be many better ways to it, but this is what I got.